# How can a very long (100+) breadcrumb trail be made usable?

Tags: website-design

I have an app that has functionality that is very similar to a choose-your-own-adventure type scenario. Basically it's a tree where you start and go through a series of decisions, and each decision affects what decisions you make next.

I would like to add something similar to a vertical breadcrumb list to let users know all of the decisions they have made, so they can go back to an earlier point and pick a different route. Users could make 100s of decisions so I am worried about page load, excessive scrolling, and users being in a position where it wouldn't be useful because they would only see ones (the last few decisions) that would be easily navigated to with the back button.

I will also have a search bar of the entire pool of decisions, even ones they did not make.

1. Is there a better way to give a history of their decisions?
2. Is there a way to improve this to make it easy to use.

Comment: While answering, I had more questions: How do you identify the items (number, phrase, question, choice)? Can you employ visualizations? Can decisions appear several times (esp. if going back, does their order change)?

Comment: They are questions and answers, and they can have relations with other questions so they don't have any real order like numbering. And yes, decisions can appear several times. I'd like to avoid visualizations because I feel it would be very slow, as the trees will probably get quite large and there are lots of decisions so it would be cumbersome to go in and out of the specific questions and the tree interface. Thanks!

Comment: I'd rethink the feature to begin with. The idea of going back 100 steps to choose a different path sounds appealing, but is it really? Would users actually want to do that?

Comment: @DA01, Yeah I agree now. I'm just going to give users the option of saving a question to a list to go back to.

Comment: @arthur.00 I think that's a great idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to handle lots of data, in your case decision history, you could add a load more option.

Not sure if there is a better way, but I would also like to suggest a different way. I hope it is possible within your concept.

You could add checkpoints at important decisions, reducing the amount of choices you present to your user.

I do have to note I think it's odd someone would choose to go back 100s of steps. I think when someone is invested enough to make 100s of different decisions, it's unlikely they would go back more than a few steps.
It makes me very curious as to what your app is precisely.

Comment: Thanks you, I like the idea of either just pushing it aside, or if people don't want to do that then I could also just keep the very popular decisions. The app orders questions and answers (so depending what question or answer you pick...) to make instructions for technical projects.

Answer (score 1):

A selection from 100+ items is rarely usable, I fear, without search and/or structure.

And I wonder whether this might get even worse because the user might want to have not only the sequence of prior decision (acting like a stack), but also might want to see paths he explored earlier - resulting in a tree (or network, depending on your scenario) of choices.

Anyway, is there any way to structure the 100+ items?

- Is there a chapter/section structure in your app?
- Is it meaningful to let the user mark certain decisions (because he is unsure and wants this item as a "system restore point")?
- Are the choices similar (numeric, or left vs. right)?
- Can you limit the history to the last 10? (Probably not a good choice.)

I'd try to add some structure, and maybe present the chapter/restore items only. Or allow to zoom into their neighborhood...

Comment: I think I'm going to go with just an optional "save this so I can come back if I need to" like in my comment above. Plus I feel this will give me a way in the future to make suggestions if people haven't marked, but would like to go back. Thank you for the answer.